# How to show balance to user in html page which is saved in database?

Tags: python, html, django

I have given balance to each user who have signed up and saved that balance in database but I am not able to show them in `html page`. Maybe I have made some mistakes in `python` files also. In `views.py` I have commented some code values which I used also but still didn't get the results. How to do it?

**models.py**

```
class Payment(models.Model):
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from decimal import Decimal
def payment(request):
    total_amount = Payment.objects.filter(
    owner=request.user)['total_amount'] or Decimal('0.00')
    for field in total_amount:
        field.amount

    context = {
        'total_amount': total_amount
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**HTML page**

```
   <li style="float: right;">Your Balance: Rs. {{total_amount}}</li>
```

**Python Shell**

```
>>> from users.models import Payment
>>> Payment.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Payment: Payment object (1)>, <Payment: Payment object (2)>]>
```

**Images of database which contains content**

```
https://ibb.co/481nzqv
https://ibb.co/B4M1NTk
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  from django.db.models import Sum
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


  @login_required
  def payment(request):
      totalamount = Payment.objects.filter(
          owner=request.user).aggregate(Sum('amount'))

      context = { 'total_amount': totalamount['amount__sum']}
      return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: It didn't work. The result is same as previous ```Your Balance is: Rs.```. After Rs. it is showing me no balance.

Comment: what does **Payment.objects.filter(
          owner=request.user)** prints ?

Comment: try executing parts of the provided query in manage.py shell and check the result. It should work.

Comment: I am not trying to aggregate. Actually I deleted the above code of aggregation. I just want it to show me the balance of that user whenever I login to that user.

Comment: what is your concept of "Balance". Would you please eloborate with the data example. What input data goes in your model and what output you are expecting?

Comment: Simply the amount which I have in my database. I want it show in my html page from database. For every user there should an amount in their page after login. It is like your balance is .... Why are you not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you return total_amount as a Payment object.

So you need just to access his attributes with {{total_amount.amount}} on the page

Or just when you pass it to the render

```
context = {
    'total_amount': total_amount.amount
}
```

You better rename it to payment it will be more clear :)

Comment: can you print the object to the console and see what is returning. Try printing with print(total_amount.__dict__)

Comment: I just want it to show me the balance of that user whenever I login to that user.

Comment: btw i saw that you are filtering by owner and in the table the column is owner_id. Are you sure that you are getting any result at all?

Comment: No No I am not getting any data from database. I am not getting any result. It is just showing me ```Your Balance is: Rs.``` which is from html page. I have used ```Payment.objects.all()``` but no result.